# creating sub pages does not work with this code in html can somebody help? once I click my wanted subpage it shows ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Tags: html

So I created my homepage, however, I am struggling to create my sub pages because I think I coded the navigation bar wrong. Could someone help and say why it so? Once I click the sub pages for example Samsung it says ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND.
for my samsunggalaxys9.html file, I copied the code below.

```
<DOCTYPE HTML!>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="author" content="john khan">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">

</head>
<body>

<header>

  <video autoplay loop class="video-background" muted plays-inline>
<source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
****<nav>
<div class="nav">
  <img src="logo.png" class="logo">
<ul class="Menü">
  <li><a href="SamsungGalaxyS9.html">Samsung Galaxy S9</a></li>
  <li><a href="iPhoneX.html">iPhone X</a></li>
  <li><a href="GooglePixel2.html">Google Pixel 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="HTCU11.html">HTC U11</a></li>
  </ul>**

</div>
</nav>** here is where I had my linking to my other HTML files, however, this doesn't work

<div class="msg">
  <h1>Die besten Handys aus dem Jahr 2018</h1>
</div>
</header>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: it would help if you put the file structure of your project in the question

Comment: what do you mean by that

Comment: Are all your html files (the one you show and all the linked ones) in the same folder?

Comment: yes they are all in one folder